# Oracle: data recovery after defining a property in Hibernate

Tags: oracle, data-recovery

By mistake I have defined a property in Hibernate

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
```

and I lost all the data I have in Oracle 10. Is there any way to rollback that transaction or recover that data?

Comment: What!? Maybe you should title this question "How to recover my data after....." Also, we can't give a specific answer unless you give a specific question.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

If this is the case, i hope you have a backup then. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you have flashback enabled and your window is big enough you could get it back that way.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a point in time restore of the full backup and the log backups to the point in time just before you deleted the data.

If you don't have a backup you are out of luck.